# If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive and $\mu(\phi) = 0$ then $\mu$ is $\sigma$-subadditive

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space. I am trying to show that if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive and $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ then $\mu$ is $\sigma$-subadditive.

My attempt:

If $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive then for any $\{A_n\}_{n = 1}^{\infty} \subseteq \Sigma$ (these $A_n$ are pairwise disjoint) we have $\mu\big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\big) = \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n).$

We must show that that $$A\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} \implies \mu(A)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n).$$

I want to to say that we can write $$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \tilde{A_{n}}$$ Where $\{\tilde{A_n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subseteq \{{A_n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and the $\{\tilde {A_n}\}$ are disjoint, because then the result follows easily, but I can't justify this. Is this the correct approach, if not how else can I solve it?

Comment: What's $\phi$ here?

Comment: @Andrew MacFie. Its the empty set.

Comment: Hint: To show $\mu(B)\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_n)$ where $B=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(B_n)$. Construct pairwise disjoint $A_n$'s from $B_n$'s for using the $\sigma$-additivity.

Comment: As you can see from my hint and @Severin's hint, you don't require the hypothesis $\mu(\phi)=0$.

Comment: **Tip:** `\emptyset` produces a symbol more easily recongizable as the empty set. Notably the empty set is denoted by a slashed through 0, not by the letter $\phi$. I have edited this symbol into your post.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Ah! Thanks. I thought it looked a bit strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let

$$ \tilde{A}_n= A_n \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j.$$

Then the $\tilde{A}_n$ are disjoint, $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} A_j= \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} \tilde{A}_j$ and you've got $\mu(\tilde{A}_n)\leq \mu(A_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is the correct approach. The construction you're looking for is classical in Measure Theory: let $(A_n)_n$ be any sequence of sets, we want to find $(S_n)_n$ such that $\bigcup A_n = \bigcup S_n$ and $(S_n)_n$ is a family of disjoint sets. Just force them to be disjoint cutting away pieces that could be shared with other sets, you should start like this: set $S_1=A_1$, $S_2=A_2 \setminus S_1 = A_2 \setminus A_1$...